# Need help writing program that makes a table

Tags: c, compiler-errors, while-loop

I am learning C and need some help. The task is to use a while loop to output a table of Fahrenheit temperatures and their Celsius equivalents. I am going from 1 degree Fahrenheit (-17 Celsius) to 300 degrees Fahrenheit (148 Celsius) with increments of 20 degrees Fahrenheit. I want to output both temperatures with 2 decimal places (I am using %.2f). I am getting the following error:

```
22:33: warning: expression result unused
  [-Wunused-value]
while ((i = upperbound), (i >= lowerbound), (i=i - increment))
                          ~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

So `lowerbound` for some reason isn't being used. I have tried several things and none have worked. Please help! Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double Tc=0;
    double Tf=0;
    double lowerbound = 1;
    double upperbound = 15;
    double increment = 1;
    int i = 15;
    while ((i = upperbound), (i >= lowerbound), (i=i - increment))
    {
        Tf=20*i;
        Tc=((5.0*Tf)-(5.0*32.0))/9.0;
        printf("%.2f\t%.2f\n", Tf, Tc);
    }
    printf("1.000000    %f\n",((5.0*1)-(5.0*32.0))/9.0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are mixing up a `for` loop with `while` loop and using `,` instead of `;`.

Comment: No, the teacher said I had to use a while loop. I have a for loop working with the same program!

Answer (score 3):

```
while ((i = upperbound), (i >= lowerbound), (i=i - increment))
```

Why are there `,` in `while`? I think you meant `for` and `,` should be `;`:

```
for ((i = upperbound); (i >= lowerbound); (i=i - increment))
```

If you are required to use a `while` loop, you cannot create your own syntax by mixing both! The syntax of `while` is the following:

```
while(expression)
{
     instruction1;
     instruction2;
     ...
}
```

where `expression` is *one* expression, which either is true or false. In your case this would be `i >= lowerbound`. You cannot put the incrementation and initialization of the loop variable in there, you have to do this separately. The initialization should be before the loop and the increment should be done at the end of the instruction block of the loop. Then the `while` loop is equivalent to the `for` loop.

Also it seems you are better of with `int` for `upperbound`, `lowerbound` and `increment`, as floating points are not required to be exact.

Comment: The teacher said I should try using a while loop, I have a for loop doing the same thing with no errors.

Comment: @user15713 Improved my answer

Comment: So what do you think I should do to fix it? I can't seem to figure it out. I have done what you said and it still isn't working, it just outputs one result.

Comment: @user15713 Well I wanted you to figure it out because it is an exercise for you, but haccks posted the complete solution.

Comment: @Nabla; I would never posted the complete solution but OP claimed that it is giving only one output.

Answer (score 1):

As you are inerested in using `while` loop, try this

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include<math.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

 int main()
 {
     double Tc=0;
     double Tf=0;
     int lowerbound = 1;
     int upperbound = 15;
     int i = upperbound;
     while (i >= lowerbound)
     {
          Tf=20*i;
          Tc=((5.0*Tf)-(5.0*32.0))/9.0;
          printf("%.2f\t%.2f\n", Tf, Tc);
          i--;
     }
     printf("1.000000    %f\n",((5.0*1)-(5.0*32.0))/9.0);
     return 0;
 }
```

See the output here: http://ideone.com/DuYi0j

Comment: That outputs only one result.

Comment: See the output in the given link.